# How to restore old user - settings (desktop - workspace)?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, .desktop

It seems that because of kernel-update, and afterwards removed older kernels, that user-settings (desktop with workspace of $user) are gone. By this the files have got invisible and disappeared (all files which $user created with their directories in /home).

How do I restore the files of $user in /home, which have got invisible ?

Window-manager is xfce4 (not unity).

Comment: - a kernel update does not do that. - kernels are not removed by an update  - restore a backup?

Comment: @Rinzwind - but all files I created are gone, so that there is somehow a new workspace with new Desktop-environment ? When files are still there, why are they invisible. Is Desktop-file gone for $user ?